# Why is javax.json from Glassfish needed as a dependency when using Yasson with JSON-B?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsonb-api, yasson

In order to use [*Java API for JSON Binding (JSON-B)*](http://json-b.net), I have found it necessary to include the following three dependencies in my [Maven POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pom):

```xml
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.json.bind/jakarta.json.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse/yasson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

The first two make sense to me.

- `jakarta.json.bind-api` is the [JSON-B API](http://json-b.net) defined by [JSR 367.](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367)
- `yasson` is the reference implementation of that API, [Eclipse Yasson](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.yasson).

➥ But what exactly does the third dependency, `javax.json` from [Glassfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish), bring to the party? Why is it required for my app to work?

If omitted, when running `Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();`, I get this error:

> javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found

I am confused because I thought Yasson *is* my JSON processing implementation.

Comment: It seems like that's a runtime dependency for this library, see Source Code box at the bottom of: https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-yasson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your code should only depend on the api `jakarta.json.bind-api`, so you don't accidentally use implementation details from `yasson`, e.g. the internal `org.eclipse.yasson.internal.ReflectionUtils`. To do this, you should add `<scope>runtime</scope>` to your `yasson` dependency. Only to run it, you need an implementation, and you picked the reference implementation `yasson`.

But [JSON-B](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jsonb) is just a layer on top of [JSON-P](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jsonp): it does the binding part, while it delegates all the raw JSON processing to JSON-P. You can mix and match any JSON-B implementation with any JSON-P implementation.

As `yasson` has to be able to work with any JSON-P implementation, it can't have a hard dependency on, e.g., Glassfish JSON-P; you have to specify it yourself (also with a `runtime` scope). The error message you see mentions Glassfish, as that's the fallback implementation JSON-P is looking for.